# Skulpt Browser Interpreter: Open links as modal superimposed over console?

Tags: python, skulpt

Is there anyway that a browser based skulpt python interpreter can OPEN webpages as a centered modal ("pop-up") then refocus on the console once the window is closed?

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: I'm not sure where to start, I think "import browser"?